# cURL post to Splunk HEC on Jenkins

Tags: java, http, jenkins, curl, splunk

I'm sending a post request with cURL to a Splunk HTTP Event Collector (HEC) in Jenkins.

When I log into the Jenkins server and execute the curl command directly on the command line, it works.  However, when constructing the command with Java and sending it through Jenkins, it's not logging anything.

```java
new ProcessBuilder().command("curl", "-k", "-X", "POST", environment.getVar("SPLUNK_URL"),
            environment.getVar("SPLUNK_CHANNEL"), "-H", "'Authorization:Splunk", environment.getVar("SPLUNK_TOKEN"), "'",
                "-H", "'Cache-Control:no-cache'", "-d","'{\"sourcetype\":\"json\",\"event\":", toSimpleJSON(output),
                "}'").start().waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I expect that the command which works on the Jenkins host would also work with Java's ProcessBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the index in the metadata of the request. Note that your HEC token may be limited to what indexes it can write to -- check this when creating your token.

```
new ProcessBuilder().command("curl", "-k", "-X", "POST", environment.getVar("SPLUNK_URL"),
            environment.getVar("SPLUNK_CHANNEL"), "-H", "'Authorization:Splunk", environment.getVar("SPLUNK_TOKEN"), "'",
                "-H", "'Cache-Control:no-cache'", "-d","'{\"sourcetype\":\"json\",\"index\":\"jenkins_index\",\"event\":", toSimpleJSON(output),
                "}'").start().waitFor(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

More details at http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAE6P